# How to make a button in tkinter that does Pillow functions

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a button that when pressed executes Pillow's image.show() function.
Before the button there are several variable text input boxes that will be added to the images, whenever the program runs the button does not do any function.

Is there a simple way to get all the pillow functions to happen after the button is activated?

I'll put the code with just one variable for example

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def CLique():
      ftitle = ImageFont.truetype("Centaur MT Italic.ttf", 240)
      W = 3125
      H = 4675
      LarguraBase = 1890
      wpercent = (LarguraBase / float(im2.size[0]))
      hsize = int((float(im2.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
      im2 = im2.resize((LarguraBase, hsize), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
      im2.save('somepic.png')
      im3 = Image.open('somepic.png')
      Fundo.paste(im3, (-75, 500), im3)
      dn = ImageDraw.Draw(Fundo)
      _, _, wn, hn = dn.textbbox((0, 0), text=str(vnome), font=ftitle)
      dn.text(((W - wn) / 2, 200), str(vnome), font=ftitle, fill=(168, 39, 0, 255))
      Fundo.show()

app = Tk()
app.title("Criador de Hand-Out")
app.geometry('1100x800')
app.configure(background="#ECDEC1")
Fundo = Image.open('D:\Projetos\Jogos\Python\Teste\Fundo.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('Poção.png')

Label(app,text="Nome do Item",background="#ECDEC1", foreground="#826637", anchor=W, font= 30).place(x=897,y=10,width=100,height=20)
vnome=Entry(app,background="#D1B786")
vnome.place(x=867,y=30,width=165,height=20)

Button(app,text="testar",command=Clique).place(x=810,y=460,width=280,height=60)

app.mainloop()
```

I've tried removing the pillow functions from within the "def Clique" but they still don't work or the image appears before inserting the text variables

Comment: Try adding `global Fundo` inside `Clique()` function.

Comment: Should `command=Clique` be `command=CLique`?

Comment: Your code fails to run due to exception on the line `wpercent = (LarguraBase / float(im2.size[0]))`.